# how to execute task within specified time in java

Tags: java, timer

I have some function as

```
func1()
{
  while (true) 
  {
    isdateok()
    { // return true or false 
    }
  }
}
```

I want isdateok() should execute till 5 secs (or any timeout which is configured)
if it returns true before the timeout then ok else continue and after 5 secs(or timeout) it should stop processing and return as timeout.

Comment: How does `isdateok` get changed?  It seems like this might be suitable for a semaphore sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I have understood your question, however the answer should be the following:

```
public boolean func1(long duration) {
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - t < duration) {
        if (isdateok())
            return true;
        else
            Thread.yield();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply..  a bit more about my code.  in while(true){} I have isdateok() function which may returns true/false.  if within specified timeout it return true then only i want to come out of loop , else if timeout occurs then it should come out of loop with timeout error.

Comment: Well, I think my answer is the right one for your needs.  When func1 returns false you have got a timeout error.  I'm going to modify it to make the timeout duration a parameter (expressed in milliseconds).

Comment: No, it is not strictly necessary but it is recommended when you have a loop that checks repeatedly the value of a variable waiting that another thread changes it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) which will allow you to execute your time-dependent tasks.

Comment: can you please provide some code merging with my example above

Comment: could you provide some more details about the code that should be executed?